# Factory retorna resultado em branco

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic

Boa Noite. Tenho uma factory com a função all que pega através de $http, um json externo, só que ele está retornando em branco. O endereço do json é http://alescrideli.com.br/kibelicia/categorias.json

```
angular.module('kibeliciaApp.services', [])

.factory('Categorias', function($http) {

var categorias = []

return {

  all: function() {
     $http.get('js/categorias.json').then(function (retorno) {
        this.categorias = retorno;
        return this.categorias;
     })
  },

  getCategoria: function(categoriaId) {
     var categoria = {};
     angular.forEach(categorias, function(categoriaCorrente) {
        if (categoriaCorrente.idCategoria === parseInt(categoriaId)) {
           categoria = categoriaCorrente;
        }
     })
     return categoria;
  },

  getProduto: function(produtoId) {
     var produto = {};
     angular.forEach(categorias, function(categoriaCorrente) {
        angular.forEach(categoriaCorrente.produtos, function(produtoCorrente) {
           if (produtoCorrente.idProduto === parseInt(produtoId)) {
              produto = produtoCorrente;
           }
        })
     })
     return produto;
  }

}

});
```

Comment: no console não aparece a linha do erro também?

Comment: no console aparece ionic.bundle.js:25642 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }. não aparece a linha exata. Ela marca a linha 25642

Comment: Depois do this.categorias = retorno falta ";" não sei se seria isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema

O erro está que você está definindo a variável categorias como variável local da função de factory, mas, no callback de sucesso do `$http.get('js/categorias.json')` você está atribuindo este valor à variável `this.categorias`.

Para corrigir segue abaixo:

```
all: function() {
 $http.get('js/categorias.json').then(function (retorno) {
    categorias = retorno;
    return categorias;
 })
},
```

retirando o `this`.

## Contextualização do this

Lembrando que, no javascript, o this é contextualizado para dentro de cada function. Ou seja, mesmo que você altere de `var categorias [];` para `this.categorias = []`, você tem um problema de contexto dentro da function de callback do `$http`. Se fosse alterar, deveria contextualizar a variável `this` em outra variável, por exemplo:

```
this.categorias = [];
var self = this;


all: function() {
 $http.get('js/categorias.json').then(function (retorno) {
    self.categorias = retorno;
    return self.categorias;
 })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar nesse Formato:

```
angular.module('MeuModulo')
.factory('MeuService', ['$http' function($http) {
    return {
        getAlgumaCoisa: function() {
            return algumacoisa;
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: @Techies, vc pode me ajudar com esse problema aqui de $http. Tentei a tarde toda aqui pra resolver isso, mais não consegui. Ou retorna em branco o resultado ou da erro

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isto seja erro de sintaxe do JSON, pois este erro geralmente é lançado por falha no parseamento.
Verifica se a função está realmente retornando o JSON ou se ele tem algum erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Eu reformulei a pergunta. Postei agora o código com a estrutura local do array. Eu quero puxar esse var categorias de um endereço http, que seria  http://alescrideli.com.br/kibelicia/categorias.json.

Answer (score 0):

Passando o seu Json pelo JSLint, está dando alguns erros...

Ta sobrando vírgula em: "textoValorOpcao": "",

Comment: Corrigi o erro do json. Agora o JSLint aprovou o json. Vou reformular o meu código e postar aqui